# Are there other distributions over functions besides the Gaussian process?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, sampling, gaussian

The Gaussian process allows you to sample a continuous function $f(x)$ evaluated at arbitrary points $\vec{x}$,
\begin{align}
f(x) &\sim GP\left(\mu(x), K(x,x')\right).
\end{align}
Are there any other distributions that allow you to sample continuous functions in this way?